# How can I find a members latest post within the original query?

Tags: mysql

I am writing a feature for my site that finds the top posters.  I select the records from the members table and order it by the number of posts that the members have.

I would like to show the information on the latest post by each of the members.  as of now, I have a right join that finds the number of articles each of the members posted(members with 0 posts not included), which is what the query is ordered by.  There is also a left join to find the member's avatar info, but that's not relevant.  Just so you know what it is.

I was never really good at writing joins and especially not at writing subqueries.  How can I add a join or subquery to find each member's latest article?  The columns needed from the 'articles' table are article_id and title.

This is my query as of now:

```
SELECT
m.member_id, m.display_name, m.avatar_id,
a.article_id, a.author_id, COUNT(a.article_id) AS total_articles,
av.attachment_id AS av_attachment_id, av.file_name              
FROM members AS m
RIGHT JOIN articles AS a ON (m.member_id = a.author_id)
LEFT JOIN attachments AS av ON (m.avatar_id = av.attachment_id)
GROUP BY m.member_id
ORDER BY total_articles DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: assuming there is a date column on the articles table?

Comment: i usually just order by article_id desc limit 1 to find the most recent record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be enough:

```
SELECT
  m.member_id,
  m.display_name,
  m.avatar_id,
  a.article_id,
  a.title,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM articles AS b WHERE b.author_id = m.member_id) AS total_articles,
  av.attachment_id AS av_attachment_id,
  av.file_name
FROM members AS m
JOIN articles AS a
  ON a.article_id = (SELECT MAX(b.article_id) FROM articles AS b WHERE b.author_id = m.member_id)
LEFT JOIN attachments AS av
  ON m.avatar_id = av.attachment_id
ORDER BY total_articles DESC
LIMIT 5
```